# PHP not displaying error or echo

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that scrapes the meta tags and title from a webpage. It should echo them but instead does nothing. I've tried  `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, `ini_set('display_errors',1);`, etc, but they do not provide any reasoning behind this.

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

$html = file_get_contents_curl("http://www.tomato.co.uk/");

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $title;

$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
{
    $meta = $metas->item($i);
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
        $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        echo $description;
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords')
        $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        echo $keywords;
}
```

Comment: Could it be you're suppressing errors here : @$doc->loadHTML($html); ?

Comment: Your script works when I run it here. Check your server log, maybe something is being reported there.

Comment: @Kei Would you recommend removing that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your script works for me:

php t.php

> tomatotomato is a collective of artists, designers, musicians and
>   writers engaged in publishing, exhibitions, live performances,
>   advertising, architecture, fashion, public installations, music,
>   television, film and graphic design.tomato is a collective of artists,
>   designers, musicians and writers engaged in publishing, exhibitions,
>   live performances, advertising, architecture, fashion, public
>   installations, music, television, film and graphic design.tomato is a
>   collective of artists, designers, musicians and writers engaged in
>   publishing, exhibitions, live performances, advertising, architecture,
>   fashion, public installations, music, television, film and graphic
>   design.

If you are running via a web browser - try viewing source - this is not valid HTML.

Comment: How did you run the script?

Comment: I ran it from the commmand line - i copied your code into a file t.php and then ran it using php command line - php t.php

Comment: Also works for me this way. Could this be a problem with my host?

Comment: From the command line run php -i and check that curl is installed

Comment: curl is installed on my computer but the host does not provide curl_init .